# ASP.NET Core Web API iis deploy successfull but not get data 500 error

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, publish

I am creating an ASP.NET Core Web API using Entity Framework (code first approach). My API is published successfully and only get a weatherForcast API data

[image: weatherForecast api data]

New API data is not fetched. I am using Windows authentication and a local database connection string. I get this error

[image: api data not get error code 500].

My next step API publish azure is work,but not work on IIS.

I am all method using but not get a solution.

Comment: The question can't be answered with the screenshot. Some http internal server error (500) occured in your webserver backend. So there is a backend problem in your webserver for this endpoint.
On windows IIS you can find additional log entries in a tool named eventlog. Just search it in your windows applications or open it directly with WIN+R `eventvwr.msc`. Usually you find IIS logging in Windows-Logs > Applcations on your server.

Comment: You could get weatherForcast API data means your asp.net core application has started, so this 500 error is specific for that new api. Using event viewer or set the stdlog to ture inside the web.config could also see what has happened.